# Parsing Doxygen config files

Tags: c#, doxygen

I want to write a simple tool for automating some doxygenation of large systems; I'd origianlly thought the .doxy file format was a simple key-value INI format but lists are done like this:

```
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
```

I plan to write my tool in C#; how can I best parse a .doxy file that will correctly understand this multi-line approach?

Comment: normally it would be the best solution to take the original C sourcecode for the config file parsing, and porting it line by lint to c#. for simple config files is that a very fast and direct approach. but with doxygen it is a little bit more complicated. I just took a look at the source code, and the config file is there parsed by a flex - generated scanner ...

Comment: you make a good point, I hadn't got round to checking the doxygen source but now I don't think I will!